# Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x>0, y=\sin \frac1x \} \cup \{(0,0\}$. Is $A$ closed? Connected? Locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x>0, y=\sin \frac1x \} \cup \{(0,0\}$. Is $A$ closed? Connected? Locally compact?

$A$ is a union of a graph of a continuous function and a singleton and therefore union of two closed sets and thus closed itself.

The set $S=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x>0, y=\sin \frac1x \}$ is the image of $f:(0,1] \to \Bbb R^2, f(x)=\sin\frac1x$ and is the continuous image of connected set so it's connected.

Now as $\overline{S} = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x>0, y=\sin \frac1x \}  \cup [-1,1]$ and the closure of a connected set is connected we have that $$S \subset A \subset \overline{S}$$ which implies that $A$ is also connected.

How can I approach local compactness? I need to show that for $x \in A$ and for any $U$ open nbhd of $x$ there exists a compact set $C$ such that for any $x \in U \subset C \subset \overline{U}$ I think?

Comment: Graph of a continuous function is closed but not in the whole space. It is closed it the subspace $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}$. Note that the domain of our function is not whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What can you say about the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{\pi/2+2\pi n}, f(\frac{1}{\pi/2+ 2\pi n}) \right)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) $A=S\cup\{(0,0)\}$ is not closed (in $\mathbb R^2$ of course, where else?): its closure is the [closed topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve#Variants) $S\cup(\{0\}\times[-1,1]).$

Its is connected, as you proved.

It is not locally compact at $O=(0,0)$, see [Steen & Seebach, *Counterexamples in Topology*, p. 138](https://books.google.fr/books?id=UNbTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA138): any neighborhood $N$ of $O$ in $A$ contains some $V=D(O,\varepsilon)\cap A$ with $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, and $V$ contains a sequence converging to some point of $\overline S\setminus S.$ Such a sequence has no accumulation point in $N$ hence $N$ is not compact.